# I2C scanner printf out of line, unclear why

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, esp8266

I have made a I2C scanner code that prints out the I2C addresses and an indicator if a device is connected to the I2C bus or not. It works perfect for the first 0...123 addresses till the last line 4...127 is printed

My question : how is it possible that the last line of addresses is printed after the "#2#" while the code illustrates that this is not possible. Hope someone can tell me how to solve this weird code behaviour.

This code is run on an ESP8266 and uses the Arduino libraries.
The same code run on a ATmega328 does not show this strange behavior.

This is the code

```
uint8_t I2C_scan(uint8_t mode){         // mode0=no output, Mode1= Summery, mode2=full output

uint8_t device_cnt=0, I2C_adr=0, cnt;
uint8_t rc, colcnt=0, columns=4;
struct I2C_devices {
    uint8_t I2C_adr;
    char*   deviceID;
    char*   type;
} I2Cdevice[]={{0x36,"AS5600","Magn Rotary"},{0x27, "PCF8574","GPIO(diplay)"},{0x3C,"DS1306","OLED-Disp"}, {0x68,"DS3231","RTC"}, 0x57, "AT24C32", "2KB Mem" };


switch (mode){
    case 2 : { 
        printf("I2C Scanner\n");
        for(cnt= 1; cnt <= 14*columns+5; cnt++) printf("%s","=");
        printf("\n     ");
        for(colcnt=0;colcnt<columns;colcnt++)  printf("%6s%02u%6s","",colcnt,"|");
        
        for(I2C_adr = 0; I2C_adr <= 127; I2C_adr++) {
            Wire.beginTransmission(I2C_adr);
            rc = Wire.endTransmission();
            if ( ((I2C_adr)%columns)==0) printf("\n %03u\t", I2C_adr); 
            if (rc) printf("0x%02X = %s  | ", I2C_adr, " - ");
            else    printf("0x%02X = %s  | ", I2C_adr, "Fnd");
        }
        printf("#1#\n");
        for(cnt= 1; cnt <= 14*columns+5; cnt++) printf("%s","=");
        printf("\n#2#\n");

    } break;
```

This is the output:

[image: This is the code output]

Comment: There are various standards on top of basic I2C that mark those highest few addresses as reserved (eg: 10 bit addressing or SMB general call).

Comment: Re-write your code so you always finish a line with `'\n'` -- not start the next line with `"\n ..."`. Doing it your way invites buffering issues causing out of order output. Just test if you are outputting the last column and output a `putchar('\n');` at that point -- as well as between your different loops.